# My carpet gets wet along an exterior wall when it rains heavily

Tags: water

The home is 15 years old.  The concrete blocks outside this area appear to be very damp at this location after a hard rain, but I don't see standing water. There is no window present on this wall, and I don't have any dampness in the wall. I have had my gutters cleaned.  Any idea who I should call?

Comment: Do you have a basement, slab, or crawl space? Is there a downspout near by? If so, does it have an extension on it to take water away from the house?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of the base of the wall where it meets the ground would be helpful.

Comment: I’ve discovered landscaping companies are decent at correcting drainage problems.  When you call the foundation or dry basement companies they usually want to start with the “when all else failed” dig and replace foundation drains—and sometimes that is the solution, but many times re-directing surface drainage will solve it.

Comment: Agree with Tyson on the drainage thing.  Start there.  Make sure the water isn't being directed toward the foundation, either by downspouts that aren't putting water far enough from the foundation, or ground that slopes back toward the house instead of away from it.

Comment: The water is coming up through a crack between your foundation and the wall - start on drainage but you might also need to have that wall / foundation area sealed. How far down below the ground level is the floor or is at at ground level ?